# How to automate a window to open & closed by remote commands

Tags: electrical, windows, electric-motor, smart-switch

I'm a software developer. I would like to be able to open and close my window automatically when there is a noise outside. So first I need a Wifi Microphone, that will stream the audio to my PC. Then I need an app that will listen and if there is noise more than specific decibels for several seconds, the window should be closed. Then if there is quiet, the window should open.

I'm not asking how to develop the software to analyze the audio and decide what to do. I'm asking about the hardware. For the microphone, I believe it won't be hard to find a microphone to Lan, or even Wifi Microphone (I'm open to recommendations). But for the robot hand that will open and close the window where should I start to look for it?

I have Googled: "Smart window" and found irrelevant links. Also search for "Smart window open close" and not found something that I can buy.

I'm open to do it myself. What kind of a motor do I need for that? Motor than can open/close using a command from a Wifi/Lan.

I have a window similar to this:
[image]

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Homesupplier-Electric-Automatic-Opening-Control/dp/B07MDJMWLN

Comment: You might look at how car windows work as well.

Comment: And I bet you want to run the window software in Windows...

Comment: Also google linear actuators.  They can be cheaper and much more flexible, but do require you to adapt the hardware.

Comment: @manassehkatz, lol ... thank you for the cheer up

Comment: why would you want to automatically open the window when there is noise outside? ... you did say that .... anyway, don't forget about the latch

Comment: Have you considered looking in the Arduino and Raspberry Pi forums?

Comment: You might consider looking at https://home-assistant.io (happy user, not a contributor to the project). They have a support forum on Discord that includes hardware support where they might be able to recommend motors for this.